# Looping XML into Single Excel Cell using XSLT

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, transform, nessus

Looking to transform (XSL, XSLT to Excel):

```
<NessusClientData_v2>
 <Report name="FAKEDB" xmlns:cm="http://www.nessus.org/cm">
  <ReportHost name="192.168.1.1">
   <HostProperties>
    <tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1</tag>
    <tag name="host-fqdn">FAKEDB</tag>
   </HostProperties>
  <ReportItem port="0" svc_name="general" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="19506" pluginName="Nessus Scan Information" pluginFamily="Settings">
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem port="1122" svc_name="availant-mgr?" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="11219" pluginName="Nessus SYN scanner" pluginFamily="Port scanners">
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem port="1122" svc_name="ssh" protocol="tcp" severity="2" pluginID="10882" pluginName="SSH Protocol Version 1 Session Key Retrieval" pluginFamily="General">
  </ReportItem>
 </Report>
 <Report name="FAKEAPP" xmlns:cm="http://www.nessus.org/cm">
  <ReportHost name="192.168.1.2">
   <HostProperties>
    <tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1</tag>
    <tag name="host-fqdn">FAKEDB</tag>
   </HostProperties>
  <ReportItem port="1122" svc_name="availant-mgr?" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="11219" pluginName="Nessus SYN scanner" pluginFamily="Port scanners">
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem port="1122" svc_name="ssh" protocol="tcp" severity="2" pluginID="10882" pluginName="SSH Protocol Version 1 Session Key Retrieval" pluginFamily="General">
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem port="47001" svc_name="www" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="11219" pluginName="Nessus SYN scanner" pluginFamily="Port scanners">
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem port="49152" svc_name="dce-rpc" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="11219" pluginName="Nessus SYN scanner" pluginFamily="Port scanners">
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem port="0" svc_name="general" protocol="udp" severity="0" pluginID="10287" pluginName="Traceroute Information" pluginFamily="General">
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem port="139" svc_name="smb" protocol="tcp" severity="0" pluginID="11011" pluginName="Microsoft Windows SMB Service Detection" pluginFamily="Windows">
  </ReportItem>
 </Report>
```

Into something like:

```
Port    Service         FQDN
====    ========        =====
1122    availant-mgr?   FAKEDB, FAKEAPP
1122    SSH             FAKEDB, FAKEAPP
47001   www             FAKEAPP
```

I can do straight conversions, but nothing like this where I add multiple node pieces into a single cell. I got a decent sample using a "generate-id" call, but I can't get it into separate columns nor can I get it to do the needed logic:

1. Only return when pluginID = 11219
2. Create a new line when the port & svc_name are not the same.

Anything someone can point me to would be great.

Thanks. Sean.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question - do a search for that. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) which can use a defined key to group `ReportItem` nodes by `@port` and `svc_name`.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
               xmlns:cm="http://www.nessus.org/cm">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="portsrvkey" match="ReportItem" use="concat(@port,@svc_name)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ReportHost">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportItem[generate-id()= 
                         generate-id(key('portsrvkey', concat(@port,@svc_name))[1])]"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ReportItem[generate-id()= 
                       generate-id(key('portsrvkey', concat(@port,@svc_name))[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="key('portsrvkey', concat(@port,@svc_name))"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <por><xsl:value-of select="@port"/></por>
      <service><xsl:value-of select="@svc_name"/></service>
      <report><xsl:value-of select="$key/ancestor::Report/@name"/></report>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

XML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:cm="http://www.nessus.org/cm">
   <ReportItem>
      <por>0</por>
      <service>general</service>
      <report>FAKEDB FAKEAPP</report>
   </ReportItem>
   <ReportItem>
      <por>1122</por>
      <service>availant-mgr?</service>
      <report>FAKEDB FAKEAPP</report>
   </ReportItem>
   <ReportItem>
      <por>1122</por>
      <service>ssh</service>
      <report>FAKEDB FAKEAPP</report>
   </ReportItem>
   <ReportItem>
      <por>47001</por>
      <service>www</service>
      <report>FAKEAPP</report>
   </ReportItem>
   <ReportItem>
      <por>49152</por>
      <service>dce-rpc</service>
      <report>FAKEAPP</report>
   </ReportItem>
   <ReportItem>
      <por>139</por>
      <service>smb</service>
      <report>FAKEAPP</report>
   </ReportItem>
</root>
```

You can then use Excel's [Workbooks.OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838643.aspx) method to import into spreadsheet:

```
Workbooks.OpenXML "C:\Path\To\Transformed\Output.xml", , xlXmlLoadImportToList
```

Comment: I've been avoiding responding in hopes I could figure this out and I just can't. The sample you provide does work except it isn't grabbing the FQDN for each occurrence and placing it into the <report> field you defined.

I would be good using the ReportHost name (IP Address) too, but even switching to that still only results in one occurrence.

Thanks. Sean.

Comment: I'm used to OPs who go ghost! But I'm not understanding as I used your posted snippet. Does report tag result empty? Possibly your actual XML is not the same as posted. Also, how are you running the XSLT? VBA can use [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204(v=vs.85).aspx).